# Чем заменить постоянное использование margin: 0 auto;?

Tags: html, css

```css
#pager {
    width: 1100px;
    height: 500px;
    background: #000;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#header {
    height: 93px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #fdd;
}
```

```html
<div id="pager">
            <div id="header">
            </div>
</div>
```

Как мне развернуть розовую часть на всю ширину страницы?

Comment: Если не прибегать ни к каким извращениям, то никак.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
#pager {
  width: 1100px;
  height: 500px;
  background: #000;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#header {
  height: 93px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fdd;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="pager"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background: #000;
}

header {
  min-height: 93px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fdd;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score -2):

Делаем позиционирование шапки абсолютным и задаём нулевое начальное расположение слева:

```
position: absolute;
left: 0;
```

```css
#pager {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #000;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#header {
    height: 93px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #fdd;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="pager">
            <div id="header">
            </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Угу, и текст `pager`-а весело «уезжает» за заголовок, скрываясь с глаз долой.

Comment: @Arhad Вы читали текст вопроса?

Comment: `Как мне развернуть розовую часть на всю ширину страницы?` — где здесь про перекрытие заголовком нижележащего содержимого?

Comment: @Arhad я ответил на основной вопрос автора?